# Please help on a complicated sql query

Tags: sql, mysql

MySQL 5.0.45

Table A has the following fields (columns):
1. transcation_id 
2. client_name
3. item_id
4. .....

Now I need to find how many transactions each client has made order by # of transactions.  The result should be like:

Tom     7 transactions
Jack    5 transactions
Mike    2 transactions

If a client has no transactions his name should not be int he list.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the number, i.e. 7 in Tom 7 transactions, the number of entries in table A, or is it a field in the table?

Comment: How many tables do you have? can you make a dump of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
select client_name, count(*) as transactions
from TableA
group by client_name
order by count(*) DESC
```

Assuming that clients without transactions aren't in the table (since the table has a transaction_id column) they won't be in the result.

Comment: this is correct, although I would do count(1) instead of count(*) slightly better performance, at least on Oracle there is difference.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select 
    Client_Name,
    count(*) as Transactions
from TableA
group by Client_Name
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: That should also have a `HAVING COUNT(*) != 0`.

Comment: @Shtééf: Thanks, actually it will count any existing record, assuming that if there are no transaction there will not be a record.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Select client_name, count(*) As MyCount
From YourTableA
Group By client_name
Having MyCount > 0
Order by MyCount Desc
```

Edit: grr, too slow again! At least I got the aliases in...